# Deserialize a Byte Array created in C# in Python

Tags: c#, python, binary, deserialization

I have a 2D jagged double array in C# which I convert to a byte array like this:

```
byte[][][] byteArray = new byte[10][][];
```

I am saving the byte array as a binary file in this way:

```
BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
{
   formatter.Serialize(stream, byteArray);
}
```

Now, I need to read the file in `python` in order to re-build there the 2D double array...

**I was trying to use `numpy.fromfile()` and would like to know how this should be done.**

Comment: Pretty sure BinaryFormatter is proprietary in the way it serializes objects. You're more than likely going to need to look at what you put in and how the file got written. Then write a custom python util to be able to read that file. And that's only if it wrote only the bytes and not a bunch of metadata with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I can tell, `BinaryFormatter` and `numpy.fromfile()` are not made to cross platforms, let alone languages. It will be easier to use a format that is more cross-platform, like JSON. The portion of converting the `double` to a `byte[]` might also have issues, e.g. because of endianness. If the performance and data requirements aren't really an issue, it'd be easier to not complicate things.

This example uses [Json.NET](http://james.newtonking.com/json) for the C#:

```
double[][] myArray = // whatever

var path = // whatever
using (StreamWriter file = File.CreateText(path))
{
    JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();
    serializer.Serialize(file, myArray);
}
```

And then in the Python all you have to do is something like:

```
import numpy
import json
path = # whatever
with open(path) as f:
    myArray = numpy.array(json.load(f))
# we now have the array! e.g.
print(myArray.dtype) # float64
print(myArray[0][0]) # 0.79449418131
```

Comment: Thanks Tim S. One more question. How can I then open the file created like this like a double array?

Comment: I think I have it:

`using (StreamReader stream = new StreamReader(path))                {        
    string strArray = stream.ReadToEnd();
    myArray = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<double[][]>(strArray);    
}`

Comment: Yep, that will work. You can skip the intermediate `string` by following the example at http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/html/DeserializeWithJsonSerializerFromFile.htm (similar to how I skipped any intermediate strings when serializing). I'd recommend this, since it should allow for better performance.